# Can't obtain values from controls through javascript in razor page

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

I have a razor page where evrything is displaying fine, but I need to be able to read the values inside a few controllers to pass them as parameters in an call to prefilter some data:

```
@page
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model MyApp.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyApp";
}

<div class="col-12 border p-3 mt-3">
    <h3>Filters</h3>
    <div class="col-12">
        <select id="portMultiselect" name="lsPorts" asp-items="@Model.Ports" multiple></select>
        <input id="searchString" type="text" name="searchString">
    </div>
</div>
    @* A "REFRESHABLE" TABLE GOES HERE...*@

@section scripts{

    @* REFRESH SCRIPT *@
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                setInterval(loadTable, 60000);
                loadTable();
            });

        function loadTable() {
            var select1 = document.getElementById("portMultiselect");
            var selectedPorts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < select1.options.length; i++) {
                if (select1.options[i].selected) selectedPorts.push(select1.options[i].value);
            }
            var searchString = document.getElementById('searchString').value;
            if (searchString != "" || selectedPorts.length != 0) {
                debugger;
            }
                fetch('/Index?handler=IndexPartial', {
                    data: {
                        searchString: searchString,
                        selectedPorts: selectedPorts
                    }
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.text();
                    })
                    .then((result) => {
                        document.getElementById('refreshable').innerHTML = result;
                    });
            }
        </script>
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to capture the selected values in my multiselect and in a text input to pass as parameters in the refresh script.

I'm correctly arriving to the expected endpoint, but Im never getting any values (It's always empty and zero) I even added a debugger in the Javascript code that I'm never hitting.

Why can't I read those values?

**EDIT:**
I have seen other ways of dealing with these, such as databindings, but as mentioned [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2168868.aspx?Avoid%20page%20refresh%20after%20submit%20button%20execute), the only way to avoid page reload is javascript and AJAX, so I still need to get these values from the javascript.

Comment: Can't you use data binding to get those values easier?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine if I add a databinding with post, the whole page refreshes, and that's not what I want, I would like to only refresh the partial view filtering the data with the values that those controls have

Comment: You sould use `select1.options.length`, not `select1.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I found a solution to my predicament as follows:

I changed the way I render the selectPicker, following the examples shown [in this page](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c%23/agregar-funcionalidad-de-busqueda-en-dropdownlistfor/827311310/):

```
@page
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model MyApp.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyApp";
}

<div class="col-12 border p-3 mt-3">
    <h3>Filtros</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <p>Puertos</p>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x =>
                x.selectPort,
                (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["MyPorts"],
                new
                {
                    @id = "portMultiselect",
                    @class = "form-control selectpicker",
                    @Value = @Model.Ports,
                    data_live_search = "true",
                    multiple = "multiple"
                })
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <p>Nombre de variable</p>
            <input id="searchString" type="text" name="searchString">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This comes with certain changes to the model you're working with, you can follow instructions to bind data as T.Trassoudaine commmented, [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/)

for this to work you need to add the specified references in your _Layout (for the bootstrap-select), you can check all the things you need to add [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

And finally, you will need to work with AJAX in javascript to pass the parameters back:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval(loadTable, 1000);
        loadTable();
    });

    function loadTable() {
        var select1 = document.getElementById("portMultiselect");
        var selectedPorts = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < select1.options.length; i++) {
            if (select1.options[i].selected) selectedPorts.push(select1.options[i].value);
        }
        var searchString = document.getElementById('searchString').value.toUpperCase();
        var searchPorts = "";
        if (selectedPorts.length != 0) {
            searchPorts = selectedPorts.join(",");
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/?handler=IndexPartial',
            data: {
                searchString: searchString,
                searchPorts: searchPorts
            },
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('refreshable').innerHTML = data;
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```